# Capybara with Poltergeist - links with data-method :delete or :patch not triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

Using Capybara with Poltergeist to click on a link with a `data-method='delete'` attribute.

Capybara moves on as if the link was successfully clicked, but no actual request hits the server.

Test logs show all the steps leading up to the displayed page ... but no request for the appropriate link.

It finds the correct link with no problem and thinks it's clicked it.

I should point out it's not a :remote link and it works in development

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
scenario "deletes a document", js: true do
  set_auto_accept_for_alert_and_confirm_dialogs
  sign_in_admin admin
  visit admin_dashboard_path
  find(:css, '#mediaDropdown').trigger('click')
  find(:css, '#documents_link').click
  find(:css, "#delete_link_#{document.id}").click
  expect(current_path).to eq admin_documents_path
  expect(Document.all.size).to eq 0
  expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t('notices.admin.documents.destroy.success'))
end
```

I've extended the wait time, added a long sleep & used`byebug` immediately before the 'delete' link & tried calling it in the console.

---

Capybara(2.10.1) - Poltergeist(1.11.0) - Rails(4.2.7.1) - jquery-rails(4.2.1) - turbolinks(5.0.1)

Comment: What are you doing in your test immediately following clicking the link?  Show your test code. Also test mode concatenates the JS assets which means an error in one can prevent later assets from being run, so make sure you don't have any JS errors showing in your console in dev mode when loading the page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've added the test. There are no Javascript errors in dev or production modes.

Comment: Is the url on which the delete_link occurs already admin_documents_path? If so then I assume your test is failing on the Document.all.size?  Your test has a couple of issues in the way it's written. First - never use current_path and eq to assert - rather use  `expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_documents_path)` .  Second  - you need to swap the order of your last two expectations.  You don't know the document is deleted until the message is displayed so check for that first before verifying the count ( Document.all.size won't wait so you need to know its been deleted before counting)

Comment: Additionally I assume clicking the delete link creates some kind of confirmation popup?  Is that a system confirm dialog? or are you overriding that with a JS driven replacement?  If so - does your set_auto_accept_for_alert_and_confirm_dialogs call handle the replacement, or does that only set for system dialogs?

Comment: Ive updated the expect statement and swapped the last two line around.  The problem is that the link with the `data-method='delete'` is being sent as a `GET` request.  It's not specific to this individual test but any `DELETE` or `PATCH` link has the same issue system wide.  The actual failure is because the `GET` route is unknown. `No route matches [GET] "/admin/documents/1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned on debugging with:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, { js_errors: true, debug: true })
end
```

This raised the javascript error `Can't find variable: $` - so jQuery wasn't being loaded.

I checked the test log to see if the javascript file was being called - it was.

I changed the javascript file to change some text on the page - but nothing happened. So the problem appeared to be with the asset pipeline.

In the end, the problem was because a `.sprokets-manifest` file had been created in the `public\assets` folder, which was otherwise empty.

I've never pre-compiled the assets on this app, so I've no idea where the manifest file came from.

Deleting the `.sprokets-manifest` file was an easy fix.